# parsing a very complicated JSON response from server for android app

Tags: java, android, sql, json

I made a successfully connection to a remote server and the response i got was 
15,000 words JSONObject.
I'm  pretty good with JSON parsing but this is nothing like I've seen before.
this is a very small part of the JSON response i'm getting :

\":\"DI_Orders\",\"Query\":\"SELECT * from TBL_Orders\",\"DataSourceID\":\"29cdf9d8-b6fe-4ea5-ac14-e5860a9494db\",\"Columns\":[{\"@ID\":\"C1\",\"@DataType\":\"System.String\",\"ColumnName\":\"Branch\"},{\"@ID\":\"C2\",\"@DataType\":\"System.Int32\",\"ColumnName\":\"DelayInDays\"},{\"@ID\":\"C3\",\"@DataType\":\"System.Int32\",\"ColumnName\":\"OrderID\"},{\"@ID\":\"C4\",\"@DataType\":\"System.Int32\",\"ColumnName\":\"ProductID\"},{\"@ID\":\"C5\",\"@DataType\":\"System.String\",\"ColumnName\":\"ProductName\"},{\"@ID\":\"C6\",\"@DataType\":\"System.Int32\",\"ColumnName\":\"Quantity\"},{\"@ID\":\"C7\",\"@DataType\":\"System.String\",\"ColumnName\":\"OrderStatus\"}],\"PrimaryKeyColumns\":{\"Column\":{\"@ID\":\"C7\"}}},{\"@ID\":\"231c9c51-00e3-4141-bf38-dae6f08d861c\",\"@StructureType\":\"Regular\",\"@Type\":\"Query\",\"@DataSourceType\":\"Sql\",\"DataItemName\":\"DI_DailySales\",\"Query\":\"SELECT * from DailySales\",\"DataSourceID\":\"29cdf9d8-b6fe-4ea5-ac14-e5860a9494db\",\"Columns\":[

it looks like some type of SQL..
does anybody knows what that is? or how do i parse it to get specific details?
I have no idea what to do with this long response..

Comment: As it stands, that is not valid JSON.

Comment: Feels like a debug response.

Comment: If the whole of it is indeed a valid Json, I would suggest using a streaming API ([jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) has one) and just parse it. Headache ahead to actually map it to anything though.

Comment: but way does the response has query in it?  it looks like some sql format..

Answer (score 2):

It will be extremely likely that this structure might change since its quite big and it is probably mapping database tables directly, meaning modifying the schema will introduce changes to the response and also your parsers. Be careful not to fail with the parsing if something changes.

I pretty much always use Jackson mapper to map the JSON responses to specific Java Models,

But in your case i don't think you should parse the whole thing, i would have a model which will just parse the things you need out of this response as opposed to everything.

It will save you a lot of time writing the parsers and debbuging if something changes. Feels more maintainable not to get the whole thing. Eventually as you require more things you can parse more stuff out.

One other option is just to put it in a json object and use it as a huge HashMap, just extract values where needed from keys. This is pretty much opposite of what i would ever do, but might work better in your case.

On a side note, whoever wrote the webservice which responds like this should be shot :)

Comment: can i show me a little example how to make HashMap to the JSONObject?

Comment: Do a new JSONObject(responseString). That is a map. then you can get things out by obj.getString(key) (or int,boolean etc.. instead of string), obj.getJSONObject(key) or obj.getJSONArray(key). JSON arrays start with key : [ "something here"], JSON Objects start with {"key": "value"}. It is pretty simple

Comment: the problem is that the JSON response from the server is so long and complex i can't understand when the JsonObject begins... is there a way to send the long JSON response to a parser so I will have an idea what to do?

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jsonview/chklaanhfefbnpoihckbnefhakgolnmc?hl=en

Comment: If it is a GET request you can do it in a browser as well.

Comment: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/advanced-rest-client/hgmloofddffdnphfgcellkdfbfbjeloo?hl=en-US

Comment: Pull the request in browser with this addon for example. you will get the whole request formatted and you will be able to see exactly how the structure is.